# Oauth: Authorizing multiple clients at once

Tags: authentication, session-management, oauth, authorization, oauth2

I have an application where the frontend app talks to 2 set of API servers: `be1.domain.com` and `be2.domain.com`
both these servers are independent entities (they do share the same top level domain, in case that is useful for this discussion), and need a user session to be able to call the APIs from FE.

We have an oauth implementation which different applications use to log the user in. This is how it generally works for 1 API server:

- FE is on fe.domain.com
- BE is on be.domain.com
- FE takes the user to oauth.domain.com, which logs the user in, and returns with an auth code on the redirect url: `fe.domain.com/redirect`
- FE extracts the auth code from the url, passes it on to `be.domain.com`
- `be.domain.com` exchanges the auth code for an access token from the oauth server for verifying the user
- Once the user is verified, `be.domain.com` creates a session for the user by setting a cookie on be.domain.com. For any further api calls from FE, this cookie is automatically sent to be.domain.com , which then returns the response

This flow works fine for maintaining the session on a single api server. In oauth parlance, we would generally call be.domain.com as a client for oauth.

When there are multiple api servers that need a session on top of the oauth session, there are visible issues:

- should we have multiple redirects, one for each client `be1.domain.com` and `be2.domain.com` and get separate auth codes for each of them? If yes, this will impact the user experience, as the user would need to be redirected to the auth server multiple times even though they have already logged in once to the FE application.
- is this typical in oauth, is this even allowed in an easier way (authorizing multiple clients at once)?
- can the FE extract the auth code and pass that to both `be1.domain.com` and `be2.domain.com` , and they can use that for authorizing both the clients? Is that allowed in oauth?
- any other way this can be handled within the oauth understanding?

**Notes:**

- I am using oauth as a login mechanism to identify the user, and create a session on top of that. I understand the session management is generally outside of direct purview of oauth.
- For the auth code flow in oauth, even though I say that `be.domain.com` is the client, the redirection url is actually `fe.domain.com`. Not sure if this is a typical setup.

Comment: Redirection will happen only once for each BE. Is that an inconvenience? It's fine to keep separate Oauth2 session cookie for BE1 and BE2. To improve UX, initialize Oauth2 session for BE2 only when the user will access BE2 APIs.

Comment: @defalt what do you mean by separate oauth2 session cookie for BE1 and BE2 ? as per my understanding, the oauth session cookie would be a single cookie, the BE1 and BE2 will maintain their own session cookies or jwts independent of this. 
Also, yes, this is my most preferred method, but I am also trying to understand how it is typically handled especially if there are real world examples

Comment: Let BE1 and BE2 manage their own session cookies. The redirect will only happen once for each BE and if the user is not accessing BE2, it will not encounter 2nd redirect. Also, if the user is already signed in at Oauth2 provider's account, the redirect will be as quick as blinking.

Comment: yes, that's mostly true, I am not averse to the solution and as mentioned above, it is my fallback if i don't get a better / typical pattern in oauth. Redirections are generally a problem when implementing mobile app oauth flows on custom tabs.